# Running Docker as a Service - Environment Variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, shell, systemd

I am attempting to run my docker container in my linux server and configure it as a systemd unit to manage itself.
My /etc/systemd/system/system.service file features this line:

```
[Unit]
Description=Your Container Name
After=docker.service
Requires=docker.service
StartLimitInterval=200
StartLimitBurst=10

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=0
Restart=always
RestartSec=2
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker exec %n stop
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm %n
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/bash -c 'docker login -u AWS -p $(aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-west-1) 0123456789.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull 0123456789.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/your-container:latest
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --rm --name %n 0123456789.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/your-container:latest -e env_var1=abc -e env_var2=def

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This has proven problematic because when I restart the service and check the status it shows this error:

```
● docker.name.service - name
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/docker.name.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Thu 2022-03-10 19:28:06 UTC; 6min ago
  Process: 11029 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --rm --name %n 0123456789.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/your-container:latest -e env_var1=abc -e env_var2=def (code=exited, status=127)
  Process: 11018 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull 0123456789.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/your-container:latest (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 10984 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/bash -c docker login -u AWS -p $(aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-west-1) 0123456789.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/your-container:latest (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 10973 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker rm %n (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 10951 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker exec %n stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 11029 (code=exited, status=127)
Process: 8174 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --rm --name %n 0123456789.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/your-container:latest -e env_var1=abc -e env_var2=def (code=exited, status=127)
```

Removing the docker -e options env_var1=abc -e env_var2=def and restarting the service then allows the service to start correctly. How do I get these environment variables to be passed to the docker container from the service? It is critical they are.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) considers everything after the image name to be a command that's passed to the container, overriding whatever is configured in the Dockerfile with `CMD`.

To provide environment variables to the container itself, your `-e` options need to appear before the image name:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --rm --name %n  -e env_var1=abc -e env_var2=def 0123456789.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/your-container:latest
```